# Where dose matplotlib find font and how to add a new one to it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

First I put my custom font `STKAITI.TTF` to `/usr/local/share/fonts`, then rebuild font cache by `fc-cache -fv`.

But I still can not use it in matplotlib.

```py
In [13]: matplotlib.font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext='ttf')
Out[13]:
['/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf',
 '/usr/local/share/fonts/STKAITI.TTF', # font is here
 '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf',
 '/usr/local/share/fonts/NotoSansSC-Regular.otf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf']
```

then:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [6]: plt.rcParams["font.sans-serif"] ## this is definded in my '~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc'
Out[6]:
['STKaiti', # is here
 'DejaVu Sans',
 'Bitstream Vera Sans',
 'Computer Modern Sans Serif',
 'Lucida Grande',
 'Verdana',
 'Geneva',
 'Lucid',
 'Arial',
 'Helvetica',
 'Avant Garde',
 'sans-serif']
```

ok...testing

```py
In [7]: matplotlib.font_manager.get_fontconfig_fonts()
<ipython-input-7-b1c4039c0e25>:1: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The get_fontconfig_fonts function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.5 and will be removed two minor releases later.
  matplotlib.font_manager.get_fontconfig_fonts()
Out[7]:
['/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf',
 '/usr/local/share/fonts/NotoSansSC-Regular.otf',
 '/usr/local/share/fonts/STKAITI.TTF', # here
 '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf',
 '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf']
```

BUT! Method below can not find it!

```
In [8]: [f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist]
Out[8]:
['cmb10',
 'cmr10',
 'STIXGeneral',
 'STIXSizeOneSym',
 'DejaVu Sans Mono',
 'STIXSizeTwoSym',
 'cmex10',
 'DejaVu Serif',
 'DejaVu Sans',
 'cmss10',
 'STIXGeneral',
 'cmtt10',
 'DejaVu Sans',
 'cmmi10',
 'STIXSizeThreeSym',
 'STIXSizeTwoSym',
 'STIXSizeFourSym',
 'DejaVu Serif',
 'STIXSizeFiveSym',
 'DejaVu Sans Mono',
 'DejaVu Sans Mono',
 'STIXNonUnicode',
 'STIXGeneral',
 'cmsy10',
 'DejaVu Sans',
 'STIXSizeOneSym',
 'STIXNonUnicode',
 'STIXSizeFourSym',
 'DejaVu Serif Display',
 'STIXSizeThreeSym',
 'DejaVu Sans Mono',
 'STIXNonUnicode',
 'STIXNonUnicode',
 'STIXGeneral',
 'DejaVu Sans',
 'DejaVu Sans Display',
 'DejaVu Serif',
 'DejaVu Serif',
 'DejaVu Sans Mono',
 'DejaVu Sans',
 'DejaVu Serif',
 'DejaVu Serif',
 'DejaVu Sans',
 'DejaVu Sans Mono']
```

Even this:

```
In [10]: matplotlib.font_manager.findfont("STKaiti", rebuild_if_missing=True)
findfont: Font family ['STKaiti'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
Out[10]: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/DejaVuSans.ttf'

In [14]: matplotlib.font_manager.findfont("STIXSizeTwoSym", rebuild_if_missing=True)
Out[14]: '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/ttf/STIXSizTwoSymReg.ttf'

In [19]: matplotlib.font_manager.findfont("STKaiti", directory="/usr/local/share/fonts/",rebuild_if_missing=True)
findfont: Font family ['STKaiti'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [19], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 matplotlib.font_manager.findfont("STKaiti", directory="/usr/local/share/fonts/",rebuild_if_missing=True)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1307, in FontManager.findfont(self, prop, fontext, directory, fallback_to_default, rebuild_if_missing)
   1301 # Pass the relevant rcParams (and the font manager, as `self`) to
   1302 # _findfont_cached so to prevent using a stale cache entry after an
   1303 # rcParam was changed.
   1304 rc_params = tuple(tuple(rcParams[key]) for key in [
   1305     "font.serif", "font.sans-serif", "font.cursive", "font.fantasy",
   1306     "font.monospace"])
-> 1307 return self._findfont_cached(
   1308     prop, fontext, directory, fallback_to_default, rebuild_if_missing,
   1309     rc_params)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1361, in FontManager._findfont_cached(self, prop, fontext, directory, fallback_to_default, rebuild_if_missing, rc_params)
   1359     default_prop = prop.copy()
   1360     default_prop.set_family(self.defaultFamily[fontext])
-> 1361     return self.findfont(default_prop, fontext, directory,
   1362                          fallback_to_default=False)
   1363 else:
   1364     raise ValueError(f"Failed to find font {prop}, and fallback "
   1365                      f"to the default font was disabled")

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1307, in FontManager.findfont(self, prop, fontext, directory, fallback_to_default, rebuild_if_missing)
   1301 # Pass the relevant rcParams (and the font manager, as `self`) to
   1302 # _findfont_cached so to prevent using a stale cache entry after an
   1303 # rcParam was changed.
   1304 rc_params = tuple(tuple(rcParams[key]) for key in [
   1305     "font.serif", "font.sans-serif", "font.cursive", "font.fantasy",
   1306     "font.monospace"])
-> 1307 return self._findfont_cached(
   1308     prop, fontext, directory, fallback_to_default, rebuild_if_missing,
   1309     rc_params)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1364, in FontManager._findfont_cached(self, prop, fontext, directory, fallback_to_default, rebuild_if_missing, rc_params)
   1361         return self.findfont(default_prop, fontext, directory,
   1362                              fallback_to_default=False)
   1363     else:
-> 1364         raise ValueError(f"Failed to find font {prop}, and fallback "
   1365                          f"to the default font was disabled")
   1366 else:
   1367     _log.debug('findfont: Matching %s to %s (%r) with score of %f.',
   1368                prop, best_font.name, best_font.fname, best_score)

ValueError: Failed to find font DejaVu Sans:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=16.0, and fallback to the default font was disabled
```

So which method really define fonts that `matplotlib` can use and how can I add my font to it?

Comment: does deleting matplotlib's cache diretory (see `matplotlib.get_cachedir()`) help?

Comment: @Stef, yes it works. But as I know `_rebuild` function is removed, no graceful way to  do it with python without restart script now.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it should also work if you explicitly add the font with [`addfont`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/font_manager_api.html?highlight=addfont#matplotlib.font_manager.FontManager.addfont). Or you may also use [`findfont`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/font_manager_api.html?highlight=findfont#matplotlib.font_manager.findfont) which rebuilds the cache if the font is not found (default is `rebuild_if_missing=True`)

Comment: @Stef, see the last part of my question, I have use `findfont` with `rebuild_if_missing=True` which does not work.

Comment: sorry, I missed that

Answer (score 0):

So I had a bit of trouble with this until I figured out the issue that is particular to me. The .ttf font files I downloaded using wget were basically empty shells.

What worked for me was downloading a zip and checking that the files were actually downloaded then I copied the files directly into the first directory I got from

```py
from matplotlib import font_manager
font_manager.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None, fontext="ttf")
print(font_manager.fontManager.ttflist)
```

I also deleted the font cache:

```
rm ~/.cache/matplotlib -rf
```

I reran the script and the list size increased and I was able to use the font in matplotlib. I think the reason why this was helpful to me was because it allowed me to see all the locations matplotlib was taking fonts from which for me was 3 different locations.